# Efficiently filtering a self join based on a separate table

Tags: mariadb

I have a table into which I've accidentally introduced mostly duplicate data, and I need to work out what are duplicates so I can have them removed. So I join table x onto itself.

Things get slow though, when I also need to filter out row ids based on content in another table, so I end up with these two sub-queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM table x
JOIN table x2 ON x.uid = x2.uid
  WHERE x.eid IN (SELECT group FROM grouping)
  AND  x2.eid IN (SELECT group FROM grouping)
LIMIT 10;
```

Can I make this more efficient somehow? The explain looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+----------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref               | rows    | Extra                               |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | grouping | index  | group           | group   | 5       | NULL              | 8804849 | Using where; Using index; LooseScan |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | x        | eq_ref | PRIMARY,eid,uid | PRIMARY | 4       | db.grouping.group |       1 | Using where                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | grouping | range  | group           | group   | 5       | NULL              | 8802822 | Using where; Using index; LooseScan |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | x2       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,eid,uid | PRIMARY | 4       | db.grouping.group |       1 | Using where                         |
```

Definition of tables and sample values below:

```
DROP DATABASE tmp;
CREATE DATABASE tmp;
USE tmp;

CREATE TABLE `e_data` (
  `eid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`eid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `eid` (`eid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
);

CREATE TABLE `user_group` (
  `eid` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `u_group` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eid`),
  KEY `u_group` (`u_group`)
);

INSERT INTO e_data (uid, created) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3);

INSERT INTO user_group (eid, u_group) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 4), (5, 4), (6, 4), (7, 7), (8, 7), (9, 7), (10, 10), (11, 10), (12, 10), (13, 13), (14, 13), (15, 13);

SELECT e1.eid e1, e2.eid e2, e1.created, e2.created FROM `e_data` e1 JOIN `e_data` e2 ON e1.uid = e2.uid WHERE e1.eid IN (SELECT u_group FROM user_group) AND e2.eid IN (SELECT u_group FROM user_group) AND e2.eid > e1.eid AND e1.created = e2.created;

+----+----+---------+---------+
| e1 | e2 | created | created |
+----+----+---------+---------+
|  4 |  7 |       2 |       2 |
+----+----+---------+---------+
```

This shows me that since "created" is the same for group 4 and 7, that's a duplicate I should look closer at removing.

Using MariaDB 10.0.21.

Comment: The query is probably transformed by the optimizer to multiple joins without subquries - run `EXPLAIN EXTENDED <query>; SHOW WARNINGS;` to see what actual sql is used. Looks like in this case the "optimization" is not very helpful one. How many rows are returned by the subquery?

Comment: @jkavalik EXPLAIN EXTENDED adds a "Filtered: 100.00" to all 4 lines.
SHOW WARNINGS does indeed show two SEMI JOINs for the grouping table and no sub queries. The subquery returns around 9M rows.

Comment: And how many rows there are in the `table`? You could add `order by x.uid` to force the order by .. limit optimization on the parameter you are interested in and change the join order.

Comment: @jkavalik There are 12M rows in `table`. I tried adding `order by x.created`. This adds `Using temporary; Using filesort` to the first line of the `EXPLAIN` above, and the SEMI JOINs remain. I may have missunderstood what to do. Performance is actually significantly worse with an `ORDER BY`, with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` saying `Queried about 242660000 rows` and counting.

Comment: Yes, performance drops if you order it by `created`, thats why I suggested ordering by `uid` as that one is indexed and significant in the query. But the order makes sense only when the LIMIT with a relatively small number is used, and you probably want all results. You might insteas create two temporary tables holding two copies of `x` which satisfy `x.eid IN (SELECT group FROM grouping)` if that would be only a part of the 12M rows (say less than 8M). What you need is tell the server it should solve the duplicity part first and only then check the subqueries.

Comment: You could just disable the optimization (semijoin or derived table merge?) and let it work the way you wrote it, or do some modifications which will forbid it anyway: `x.eid+0 IN (SELECT group FROM grouping)` (and the same for x2) - the `+0` is an expression which cannot use index, so the join will HAVE to go the other way.

Comment: Can you show us the `CREATE TABLE` script for both tables? And explain what the query is supposed to return?

Comment: @jkavalik Sorry, I misread your comment and missed the uid bit. I do want all the data yes, so the ordering sounds like it won't help then. I tried +0, but sadly that also made performance worse. I'm struggling to understand your suggestion of creating "two tables holding two copies". If I have two tables, then it would be the same as it is now? And there wouldn't be two copies of anything, since I'm matching against the same table twice?

Comment: @ypercube I've added a sample set of tables, data and a query demonstrating the problem. The query works correctly as it is, it just doesn't scale well to millions of rows.

Comment: I would try adding an index on `(uid, created)` for the query you added in the update - that has the additional `AND e2.eid > e1.eid AND e1.created = e2.created` conditions.

Comment: user50849 just wanted to add that you are missing one check and I see in the edit that the "real" query contains it (`AND e2.eid > e1.eid`).. How many duplicates do you expect to get? Probably the most efficient plan will be full table scan on e1, but it seems from the explain you showed that the optimizer goes a totaly different way.. And I second that index suggestion from @ypercube. If you add it then please update with the new explain results.